# Word request: A word meaning "self-describing" or "true to its name"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an operational manual for a software development team. The manual contains the communication methods used to share status in case of a systematic problem.

The main communication methods is [Slack channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)), each having a name like `emergency-database-events` or `public-status-notifications`.

I'd like to find an adjective which means "the channel contains what it name says". It is analogous to the eponymous, but instead of naming something after a person, it is naming something in a fashion that describes its nature.

Comment: Each channel is named according to its function or purpose.

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane! That wording is good. Is there a single word that conveys that message?

Comment: Yes: its **name**. I get the impression you are trying to explain something that does not need explaining.

Comment: How would you convey that in a sentence? Saying that the channel name represents its content? It is not always the case with other channels.

Comment: I'd say something like "The channel names have the obvious interpretation".

Comment: Thanks. I'd be happy to know why it is down voted. Is it unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***self-explanatory***
>
> easily understood from the information already given and not needing further
> explanation:

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-explanatory)

Answer (score 1):

***Self-evident***

> clear or obvious without needing any proof or explanation

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/self-evident)

A word used in the above definition might also work:

***Obvious***

> easily seen, recognized, or understood

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/obvious)

Answer (score 0):

***Congruous***

Congruous with its name. The channel content is congruous with its name.

congruous  • adjective. :  being in agreement, harmony, or correspondence